# Getting Values of Uncheck Checkboxes

Tags: php

Is it possible to get the value of my unchecked checkboxes? How Could I do that? I just wanna get the value of it and save it in my database. Please Help me.

Here is my code:

This code only display the value of the checkbox, but my client wanted to get also the value of the unchecked checkboxes and save the value of that unchecked checkboxes in the database and mark as 'ABSENT' while the checked boxes that has checked will get the value and save into database and mark as 'PRESENT.'

```
 <?php

    $connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); 
    mysql_select_db("db_fpes",$connect); //select the table 

    $result_prof  = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM professors where fac_stat = 1 ORDER BY Faculty_status       DESC,Faculty_name ASC ");
    $row_prof = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_prof);
    $total_prof = mysql_num_rows($result_prof);

    if(isset($_POST['btnSubmit'])) {
        $checkBox = $_POST['chkFile'];
for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($checkBox); $i++)
        {
            echo $checkBox[$i];
        }

    }
?>
<?php do{ ?>

<form name="formDemo" method="post" action="">

    <input type="checkbox" name = "chkFile[]" value = "<?php echo $row_prof['Faculty_code']; ?>"/> </td> <!--//edit,delete -->


<?php } while($row_prof = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_prof));?>
 <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: You know that a check box only can be 0 or 1 and you want to store this in a db?

Comment: they are not included in `POST/GET` if they are unchecked.

Comment: `checkboxes - checked_checkboxes = unchecked_checkboxes`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I've update my questions. Please do help me.. I am a newbie in web development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your updated question, a modified and adjusted answer. Have a look at the code below; it does what you want. By the way, I'm using prefix-chars for variables to easier identify the datatype (a = for arrays, i = for ints, r = for resources etc.). Also I'd like to advice you to Look into PDO or MySQLi libraries since mysql-library is deprecated ([as of PHP 5.5.x](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php)).

```
<?php       
    $rConnection = mysql_select('localhost', 'root', 'yourpwd');
    mysql_select_db('yourdb', $rConnection);

    $rQuery = mysql_query("
        SELECT      * 
        FROM        `professors` 
        WHERE       `fac_stat` = 1
        ORDER BY    `Faculty_status` DESC,
                    `Faculty_name` ASC");

    $aAllCheckboxValues = array();

    while($aRow = mysql_fetch_assoc($rQuery)) {
        $aAllCheckboxValues[] = $aRow['Faculty_code'];
    } 

    if(isset($_POST['btnSubmit'])) {
        $aChecked   = array();
        $aUnchecked = array();

        foreach($_POST['chkFile'] as $sFacultyCode) {
            # Validate if the value of the posted checkbox is valid
            if(in_array($sFacultyCode, $aAllCheckboxValues)) {
                $aChecked[] = $sFacultyCode;
            }
        }

        $aUnchecked = array_diff($aAllCheckboxValues, $aChecked);

        echo '<pre>';
        echo 'Checked:';
        print_r($aChecked);
        echo 'Unchecked:';
        print_r($aUnchecked);
        echo '</pre>';
    }
?>
<form name="formDemo" method="post" action="">
    <?php foreach($aAllCheckboxValues as $sFacultyCode) { ?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="chkFile[]" value="<?php echo $sFacultyCode ?>"/> <?php echo $sFacultyCode ?><br/>
    <?php } ?>
    <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: What if sir if the data is from my database?

Comment: You'll have to further explain what you mean. For example you could fetch the needed checkboxes with a SQL-query, and outputting them to your form...

Answer (score 1):

Check that values with `isset()` so if the value is not empty then the checkbox is set. Otherwise its unchecked.

```
if(isset($_POST['mycheckbox']) {
    echo 'checked';
} else {
    echo 'unchecked'
}
```

Comment: Sir what if the value is from the database? look at the sample code above, Please Help me.. :)

Answer (score 1):

While a checkbox can only have a single value which is either sent or not, if you want to always have some sort of response you can use a hidden html field with the unset value, this will only be sent in if the checkbox isn't active:

```
<input type="hidden" name="some_checkbox" value="Unchecked" />
<input type="checkbox" name="some_checkbox" value="Checked" />
```

Make sure they have the same name and that the hidden field is defined *before* the checkbox.

Comment: This solution is underestimated because it solved my problem.